# Criar miniatura com Plupload

Tags: php, thumbnail

Estou tentando criar miniaturas durante o upload de imagens usando o Plupload porém sem sucesso, salvando as miniaturas em uma pasta e as imagens reais em outra.

Achei esse link em inglês que diz fazer isso, porém não consegui fazer funcionar.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762529/plupload-create-multiple-sized-thumbnails?answertab=active

Alguém tem ideia de como fazer isso?

Comment: Consegui fazer o upload, porém não redimensiona as imagens. Já não sei mais o que fazer

Comment: Não consegue mostrar o que já foi feito? As miniaturas serão X% menores que a real? Ou tamanho fixo?